# Unix: why I need to close the input FIFO to my program before I can read from its output FIFO

Tags: python, unix, io-redirection, mkfifo

I've got a problem: I have one program running in a shell that does some calculations based on user input, and I can launch this program in an interactive way so it will keep asking for input and it outputs its calculations after user press enter. So it remains open inside the shell till user types the exit-word.

What I want to do is to create an interface in such a way that user has to type input somewhere else off the shell and using pipe, fifo and so on, input is carried away to that program, and its output goes to this interface.

In a few word: I have a long running process and I need to attach, when needed, my interface to its stdin and stdout.

For this kind of problem, I was thinking to use a FIFO file made by mkfifo command (we are in Unix, especially for Mac user) and redirect program stdin and stdout to this file:

`my_program < fifofile > fifofile`

But I've found some difficulties about reading and writing to this fifo file. So I decided to use 2 fifo files, one for input and one for output. So:

`exec my_program < fifofile_in > fifofile_out`

(don't know why I use exec for redirection, but it works... and I'm okay with exec ;) )

If I launch this command in a shell, and in another one I wrote:

`echo -n "date()" > fifofile_in`

The echoing process is succesful, and if I do:

`cat fifofile_out`

I'm able to see my_program output. Ok! But I don't want to deal with shell, instead I want to deal with a program written by me, like this python script:

```
import os, time;

text="";
OUT=os.open("sample_out",os.O_RDONLY | os.O_NONBLOCK)
out=os.fdopen(OUT);
while(1):
  #IN=open("sample_in",'w' );
  IN=os.open("sample_in",os.O_WRONLY)
  #OUT=os.fdopen(os.open("sample_out",os.O_RDONLY| os.O_NONBLOCK |os.O_APPEND));
  #OUT=open("sample_out","r");
  print "Write your mess:";
  text=raw_input();
  if (text=="exit"):
    break;
  os.write(IN,text);
  os.close(IN);
  #os.fsync(IN);
  time.sleep(0.05);
  try:
    while True:
        #c=os.read(OUT,1);
        c=out.readline();
        print "Read: ", c#, " -- ", ord(c);
        if not c:
            print "End of file";
            quit();
            #break;
  except OSError as e:
    continue;
    #print "OSError"
  except IOError as e:
    continue;
    #print "IOError"
```

Where:

`sample_in, sample_out` are respectively fifo files used for redirections to stdin and stdout (so I write to stdin in order to give input to my_program and I read from stdout in order to get my_program output)

`out` is my os.fdopen file descriptor used for getting lines with `out.readline()` instead of using `OUT.read(1)` (char by char)

`time.sleep(0.05)` is for delay some time before go reading my_program output (needed for calculations, else I got nothing to read).

Whit this script and my_program running in background from the shell, I'm able to write to stdin and read from stdout correctly, but the journey to achieve this code wasn't easy: after have read all posts about fifo and reading/writing from/to fifo files, I came with this solution of closing the IN fd before reading from OUT even if the fifo files are different! From what I read around internet and in Stackoverflow articles, I thought that this procedure was for handle only one fifo file, but here I deal with two (different!). I think it is something related to how I write into sample_in: I tried to flush to look like `echo -n` command, but it seems useless.

So I would like to ask you if this behaviour is normal, and how can achieve the same thing with `echo -n "...." > sample_in` and in other shell `cat sample_out`? In particular, cat is outputting data continuously as soon as I echo input in sample_in, but my way of reading is with data blocks.

Thanks so much, I hope everything it's clear enough!

Comment: `exec foo <in >out` isn't just redirection, it's also terminating your shell and giving `foo` its PID. It would need to just be `exec <in >out` to be a pure redirection.

Comment: As for the behaviors you're asking about, they depend on details not given in your question -- especially what kind of buffering the program you're running attached to the FIFOs uses. If it's reading its input in larger-than-line-buffered chunks, needing to close that stream to flush everything through is *utterly* expected, but because you haven't provided a [mcve], we can't see your problem ourselves, so speculation/"if"s are all we've got to go on.

Comment: ...as for a title that actually gives people a more concrete idea of what you're asking -- let me suggest *Why do I need to close the input FIFO to my program before I can read from its output FIFO?*. Beyond that, the question needs a lot of work to tighten it up for readability and terseness; see [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Thanks for your resp. I don't know what kind of buffering the program uses, because it's not my: think of it as a black box, anyway I think it's reading line by line like shell command. Okay, I'll review my question.

Comment: (personally, I *wouldn't* use a FIFO for the reattaching semantics you want here -- or at least, not a FIFO alone; a UNIX or TCP socket that can be attached to multiple times shimmed to a pair of FIFOs makes much more sense -- but if working code for that is what you want, it should be in the context of a question that's *only* asking about that, and not digressing into close/flush ordering issues).

Comment: I understand that the program isn't yours, but it *is* your responsibility to provide us with a comparable-enough black box that can be used to see the same problem ourselves, and test whether our fixes work. If that's something as easy as `cat` -- reading from input and writing to output -- then it's, well, easy. :)

Comment: Yes, it's like cat in the sense that it takes input in stdin, do something not inherent to my question, and outputs the result in stdout. For testing purpose, you can choose any program /shell command you want that takes input and outputs a result (like I don't know, maybe `cat` itself it's right for this). Hope I'm clear enough!

Comment: Not really clear enough, no. I'm still not clear on which question you're actually asking -- if the focus is on the *why* of your current approach not working the way you want, or the *how* of what it would look like to build an implementation that works correctly (ignoring the attempted approach and its faults) for being able to detach and reattach to a long-running process. I'm also unclear on what constraints if any you have around how much output to accept associated with each line of input (for example).

Comment: A program run this way is called a coprocess. There are so many possible issues. I have found an article (maybe too long) trying to summarize the topic: https://www.ict.griffith.edu.au/anthony/info/co-processing/general_hints.txt

Comment: Backing up -- why do any of this, rather than use `p = subprocess.Popen(['my_program'], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)`, read from `p.stdout` and write to `p.stdin`? There's not even a compelling case for `O_ASYNC` -- just do the reads in blocking mode in a separate thread and throw results on a Queue.

Comment: See ie. http://stefaanlippens.net/python-asynchronous-subprocess-pipe-reading/

Comment: Python subprocess make the program to close after have interacted with (I can send input and read output only once, then the subprocess close), for this I choose to use fifo files and keep the program running in separate thread. The co-processing sounds interesting, I'm still looking at it